# Having troble with my text running

Tags: text

I need some help with some overflowing text on my webpage that I am designing for school. I'm two weeks into my HTML/CSS webdesign class, so I am unable to use some of the more advanced coding. I am just curious as to why the text on the right hand side of my website(I'll post a link to jsfiddle in the comments because I cannot figure out how to add it in this original post.) doesn't want to stay on its side of the screen. Any help?

here are my codes(both CCS and HMTL):

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* temporary background color for testing purposes  */

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
el,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/* My Styles */

body {
  font-family: Arial, Hevetical, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80% margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  padding: 3em;
  height: 330px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}
nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
nav a {
  padding: .25em 5em;
  background-color: #235B8A;
}
section {
  padding: 3em;
}
footer {
  padding: 3em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
aside {
  padding: 3em;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 250%;
}
h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 150%;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 80%;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 32%;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
}
.col-2-3 {
  width: 65% float: left;
}
.cleafix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<title>Crystal Coast Theater</title>
<link href="CSS/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../CSS/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header style="text-align:center">
    <a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/index.html"><h1> Crystal Coast Theater.
</h1></a>
    <nav style="text-align:center">
      <a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/event.html">Events</a>
      <a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/ticket.html">Tickets</a>
      <a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/contact.html">Contact us</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container cleatfix">
    <aside class="col-1-3">
      <h2>Upcoming events:</h2>
      <p><span class="emphasis">May 22&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;June 8:</span>&nbsp; Daring Last Days of Blackbeard</p>
      <p><span class="emphasis">June 11&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;June 29:</span>&nbsp; Ghost Stories of the Crystal Coast</p>
      <p><span class="emphasis">July 3&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;July 20:</span>&nbsp; Beach Rental</p>
      <p><span class="emphasis">July 23&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;August 10:</span>&nbsp; The Siege of Fort Macon</p>
    </aside>
    <section style="text-align:center" class="col-2-3">
      <h2>Your Down East Playhouse</h2>
      <p>The Crystal Coast Theater is located in downtown Moorehead City. It features local talent performing in both renowned plays and in works written by some of the Crystal Coast’s own talented playwrights.</p>
      <br>
      <p>The Crystal Coast Theater also offers educational performances that bring to life the history and culture of the 85 miles of coastline that are favorite destinations for tourists.</p>
      <br>
      <p>Check out our upcoming events and make plans to come and see one of our shows.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer style="text-align:center">
    <small>Copyright &copy; 2015 Paul Bernhardt Enterprises</small>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

-dark_nemesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix it:

```css
section {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3em;
    position: relative;
}
```

Greetz

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! That was driving me absolutely crazy! The thought of using the overflow property, but obviously forgot to test it out. Thanks again!

Comment: NP :) every beginning is hard ;)